# Mantener traducción al refrescar la página

Tags: javascript

Tengo una página en html multi-idioma. La traducción la hago con el script de abajo: únicamente asigno un ID al elemento que quiero traducir y luego lo agrego al JS.

El problema es cuando actualizo la página: la traducción se borra una vez actualizo la página, y mi objetivo es que cuando el usuario vuelva, se quede su preferencia guardada. **¿Cómo modifico el código para que la traducción permanezca?**

```
var strings = {
    espanol: {
        //PRINCIPAL//
        lang: "<i class='fa-duotone fa-earth-americas fa-lg'></i> Idioma",
    },
    english: {
        //PRINCIPAL//
        lang: "<i class='fa-duotone fa-earth-americas fa-lg'></i> Language",
    }
}

$( ".espanol" ).on( "click", function() {
    // update to espanol
    localizeStrings('espanol');
});
$( ".english" ).on( "click", function() {
    // update to english
    localizeStrings('english');
});

// default language 
var Lang = "espanol";

// localize with default language
localizeStrings(Lang);

// update selected language   
function localizeStrings(strLang) {
    $(strings[strLang]).each(function(key, lang){
        $.each(lang, function(id, string) {
            $("#"+id).html(string);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Para esto están las cookies.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví Lo sé, pero soy nuevo y no sé como implementarlo :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparte de las cookies, puedes usar [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Es un objeto que almacena valores dentro del navegador, estos son modificables, pero no se eliminarán hasta que se elimine manualmente.

```js
var strings = {
    espanol: {
        //PRINCIPAL//
        lang: "<i class='fa-duotone fa-earth-americas fa-lg'></i> Idioma",
    },
    english: {
        //PRINCIPAL//
        lang: "<i class='fa-duotone fa-earth-americas fa-lg'></i> Language",
    }
}

$( ".espanol" ).on( "click", function() {
    // update to espanol
    localStorage.setItem("lang", "espanol");
    localizeStrings('espanol');
});
$( ".english" ).on( "click", function() {
    // update to english
    localStorage.setItem("lang", "english");
    localizeStrings('english');
});

// default language 
var Lang = localStorage.getItem("lang") || "english";

// localize with default language
localizeStrings(Lang);

// update selected language   
function localizeStrings(strLang) {
    $(strings[strLang]).each(function(key, lang){
        $.each(lang, function(id, string) {
            $("#"+id).html(string);
        });
    });
}
```

Explicando un poco más a fondo esto, puedes obtener el valor `lang` con `getItem()`.

```
localStorage.getItem("lang") || "english";
```

Lo que está pasando aquí es que estás poniendo dos posibles valores, el valor que se encuentre en el almacenamiento o `english`. Recuerda que un item inexistente en `localStorage` dará `null`, por lo que entre `null` y un string, JS elegirá al string porque arrojará `true` (Comparándolo son con un condicional: `if("abc") console.log(true) // true`)

Comment: Amigooo! Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta y explicación, me funcionó perfectamente! De verdad muchas graciaas.